# UIViewController init code: difference between initWithNibName and viewDidLoad

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I think we can write init code in the following two places

- `initwithNibName`
- `viewDidLoad`

what the difference.

I think `initWithNibName` happens before `viewdidLoad`, what's the case we must do some init stuff in the `initWithNibName`?

Answer (score 2):

`initWithNibName` would be called first. This is the **designated initialiser** for `UIViewController`; in other words, no matter what other methods you might call to init a `UIViewController`, you will end up with a call to `initWithNibName` somewhere down the line.
For example, if you just call `[[UIViewController alloc] init]`, the default behaviour is to attempt to load a nib file that has the same name as your view controller class.

`viewDidLoad` is called later on, after the view has loaded. To quote the [API docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLoad):

> This method is called after the view controller has loaded its view
>   hierarchy into memory. This method is called regardless of whether the
>   view hierarchy was loaded from a nib file or created programmatically
>   in the loadView method. You usually override this method to perform
>   additional initialization on views that were loaded from nib files.

Have have a careful read of the `UIViewController` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to gain a clearer understanding.

**What goes where?**

The sort of code that goes into `initWithNibName` is the same as for any `init` method: usually setting any necessary properties.

As for `viewDidLoad`, in here you might put code that needs to be run once the view hierarchy is loaded into memory. For example, if you want to programmatically do something to a `UIView` that your controller is responsible for, you do it here, because the UIView wasn't loaded into memory at the time when `init` was called.

A common mistake is for people to try to send messages to `self.view` (or subviews) in the `initWithNibName` method and wonder why it has no effect. It has no effect because `self.view` is nil at that point!

Comment: additionaly you can say, that the init method as **constructor** is a good point where you can **pass parameters** you can use in `viewDidLoad`. But because `viewDidLoad` will be called first, when the controller is pushed, you may also define own setter methods. I prefere the way of the **constructor** because it has a better overview of the exisiting options ;)

Comment: "viewDidLoad will be called first"? It's never called first. Init methods will always be called first.

Comment: Oh, I think I get you now.

Comment: first in meaning of "if condition 'push' is true, it will be called". You can say also "will be called after the controller..." ^^